# Remove dropdownlist down arrow symbol in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to hide the down arrow symbol in the `@Html.DropDownList`. How to override the default dropdownlist style.

Please see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use css to set custom apperiance to your dropdown:

```
.customDropDown { -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; 
// add background image what you like
}
```

And add this class to your dropdown :

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownID", String.Empty, new {@class="customDropDown "} )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override default styles from native CSS, but it while support only web-kit borwsers

```
.dropDown{
webkit-appearance:none
//and change style whatever you want
}
```